# How to update null values with sequence number?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this

```
id val
1  null
2  10
3  null
4  null
5  7
```

I want to get

```
id val
1  1
2  10
3  2
4  3
5  7
```

I tried to do it like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE new_val START 1

UPDATE tb1
SET val = new_val
WHERE val is null
```

But I get an error that new_val doesn't exist

Comment: Read the documentation for [sequence manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I used nextval but still it writes that new_val doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `nextval()` and provide the sequence name as a string:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE new_val 1;

UPDATE tb1
  SET val = nextval('new_val')
WHERE val is null;
```

Another option is to use `row_number()`

```
UPDATE tb1
  SET val = t.rn
FROM (
   select id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
   from tb1
)
WHERE tb1.val is null
  and tb1.id = t.id;
```

`id` is assumed to be the primary key of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You get the next value of a sequence with the [`nextval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html#id-1.5.8.23.4.2.2.1.1.1.1) function. The function takes [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) as argument type, for which you can supply the name of the sequence (as single quoted string) or the object identifier:

```
nextval('new_val')
```